# Javascript code annotation

Tags: javascript, ide, annotations

I am picking up a Javascript project.  I am new to Javascript and trying to find an IDE that I feel comfortable.  I found that all the functions are annotated nicely.  I guess that should be used by some IDE to provide auto-complete features.  I tried VS.NET, Sublime and WebStorm.  None of them do that.

```
/**
* Get objects matching particular criteria
*
* @param {String} [criteria] Criteria
*
* @return {Company.Something[]} An array containing all matching object.
*/
Match: function () {
  .
  .
  .
},
```

Comment: There might be some IDE that relies on these, but they are mainly used by docs generators I think.

Comment: Actually Sublime has some kind of autocomplete. Every variable name in a document that is used once is available for autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Sublime Text installed you can install the the DocBlockr package. It automatically creates placeholders based on the code and it also works for PHP documents.

https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs

Comment: You are right.  Those are coming from Sublime Text DocBlockr package.  I think I will settle with Sublime Text for now since the original writer was using that